# Ghost how to add custom template post

Tags: ghost-blog

I am building a Ghost blog and for one of my menu pages I want a custom post type.

**What I want:**
I want to be able to add new posts on one single page: agenda. This post has to have a three fields: image, content and date of event

**What I did:**
I created a page-agenda.hbs file, I used the default page.hbs. Then I created a post-agenda.hbs using the default.hbs which I customized

**Problem**
How to refer to my customized post template in the CMS of Ghost. I.e. how to add new posts of type agenda?

Any tips will be helpfull

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm not sure which, but this question is either about using packaged software (not programming) or shows a complete lack of effort in figuring out how to solve the programming problem.

Comment: I edited my question , I surely put effort in finding how to solve but did not succeeded yet.

Comment: Show all of your work. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Ghost doesn't have custom post types. You can tag a post and then make a page that shows those tags using the {{get}} helper but all the posts will still show up in the main index feed. There is a proposed fix for this using channels here: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Channels-101

Comment: Ok thanks you a lot! Do you know if there is another blogging framework or CMS that does allows custom post templates? And is written in JavaScript and not php

Comment: Sorry no, I thought about writing one though. Hexo at https://hexo.io/ does a good job if you want just a static site generator and no back-end admin.